# How to lock the zooming in Excel without resorting to vba

Tags: excel, locking, zooming

I am developing a workbook of multiple sheets that will be used by multiple users, and I want the individual sheets to have the zooming locked (user should not zoom in or zoom out), is there a quick way to do this without VBA?

If VBA is the only solution, what's the simplest code?

Thanks

Elie

Comment: [so] is a site for _professional and enthusiast programmers_ If you want to do this without using VBA then this is not a programming question and it's off-topic.

Comment: Why are you using the `Excel-VBA` tag to target VBA programmers to ask them how NOT to use VBA?

Comment: So a prerequisite to using your workbook is having eyesight as good as yours? What if your boss has better eyesight and wants it zoomed down further then locked? How will you do your work?

Comment: @HoboSapiens If you read my question till the end, I did not eliminate the VBA option, so this is still a programming question. My main point however is about finding an efficient solution, whether it's VBA or normal Excel.

Comment: @SilverShotBee same comment as above

Comment: @Jeeped the zoom lock will only be used only for sheets with simple summary tables, which will be set at 130% and easy to read, it is to ensure consistency.

Comment: @lallous999 most people will read your title, which says without resorting to VBA, and think "why is it here". That's why you've been downvoted

Comment: @SilverShotBee thanks for the note, I am new to stackoverflow, I will correct that in my next questions

Answer (score 1):

It might be best to reset the zoom factors each time the workbook is opened. Removing zoom functionality altogether for the duration of any editing session could lead to errors that could have been avoided if a user was able to zoom into the worksheet to verify something. Allowing them zoom functionality while resetting each worksheet's zoom factors for other users seems a comfortable compromise.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, look to the *Project Explorer* in the upper left. If it is not available, you can open it with View ► Project Explorer or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Double-click on *ThisWorkbook*. This should open a new pane to the right titled something like *Book.xlsm - ThisWorkbook (Code)*. Paste the following into the new pane.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim w As Long, ow As Long
    On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ow = ActiveSheet.Index
    For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(w).Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    Next w
    Worksheets(ow).Activate
Safe_Exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Adjust the zoom level in `ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80` to suit your own purposes. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).

Change the individual worksheet zoom level to something you consider atrocious. Save your workbook as either a *Macro-enabled workbook* (e.g. .XLSM) or *Excel Binary workbook* (.XLSB).

When you reopen the workbook all individual workbook zoom levels will be reset to the level you noted. Individual zoom setting for each worksheet may be accommodated but I thought a loop with a single zoom level would be easiest to get started.

Comment: @lallouss999 - Zooming is an *Ease of Access* feature and should not be removed from a user's 'toolkit'. If you are trying to *hide* some things from view through locking the zoom factor, there are better ways of accomplishing this than removing a very useful feature.